# Angular 2 - add key to router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I wonder if there is a way to add a key to the `Routes` array, so when I need to use a route I can use the key instead of the explicit url.

My problem is that during the develop process I need to change some url, and at the moment I need to **search-and-replace in the whole project** where I have these urls.

Using keys I would **change the url only in the routing module file**.

To clarify my question, I want to change this code:

```
this.router.navigate(['user', userId, 'profile']);
```

In something like:

```
this.router.navigate('userProfileUrl', {id: userId});
```

And in my routing definition have something like:

```
{ userProfileUrl => 'user/:id/profile' }
```

As done in other frameworks.
**For example:**

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

[Ruby-on-rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

================ UPDATE ================

I opened a feature request:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24775

Comment: do you want to pass dynamic id to the url?

Comment: Do you mean having `id` as a parameter? If this is the question, the answer is yes. I have urls with params.

Comment: so you need to access the params in the component?

Comment: Yes, of-course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can
First in your router from app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
     path: 'app',
     component: AppComponent,
     children: [ 
      {
        path: 'user/:id',
        resolve: {
          data: UserDetailResolver,
        },
        component: UserDetailComponent,
      },
     ]
    ]),
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
```

Your router navigation could be:

```
this.router.navigate(['app', 'user'], { queryParams: {id: 10} });
```

The second param of router.navigate is defined [HERE](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

Some more:
If you want to pre-fetch the data before the component even render,
you could use the UserDetailResolver above, see how to implement [Resolver in angular router](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

Comment: This is not what am I asking for. Please read the feature request to understand what I am looking for.